# How do I clear a Python threading.local object?

Tags: python, multithreading

How can I clear all the attributes off an instance of Python's [`threading.local()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.local)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can clear it's underlying `__dict__`:

```
>>> l = threading.local()
>>> l
<thread._local object at 0x7fe8d5af5fb0>
>>> l.ok = "yes"
>>> l.__dict__
{'ok': 'yes'}
>>> l.__dict__.clear()
>>> l.__dict__
{}
>>> l.ok
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'thread._local' object has no attribute 'ok'
```

Accessing the `__dict__` directly is specifically called out as a valid way to interact with the `local` object in the `_threading_local` module documentation:

> Thread-local objects support the management of thread-local data.
>      If you have data that you want to be local to a thread, simply create
>      a thread-local object and use its attributes:
>
> ```
>   >>> mydata = local()
>   >>> mydata.number = 42
>   >>> mydata.number
>   42
> ```
>
> You can also access the local-object's dictionary:
>
> ```
>   >>> mydata.__dict__
>   {'number': 42}
>   >>> mydata.__dict__.setdefault('widgets', [])
>   []
>   >>> mydata.widgets
>   []
> ```